# In Rails Test changes to objects not reflecting in Database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails 3 application, in which I am trying to write a test-case? When the test case loads, I can see that it is creating the objects corresponding to the fixtures in the database. However, if I change the object within the test case or create another object they do not reflect in the database. Further, if I find the newly created object that is happening correctly.

What is happening here? Also, how can I get the changes to reflect in the database?

Comment: Can you share your test case?

Comment: The testcase is quite simple: In it I do
blog.url = "http://newval.com"
blog.save
debugger
# I look in the database and the new value does not reflect

Comment: While in the debugger, what does `blog.errors.full_messages` give you? And how do you check that the value is in the database?

Comment: It saves it properly. I go the database directly and look up values there. It does not change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your test_helper.rb, the use_transactional_fixtures option is probably set to `true`. This means that every test is wrapped in a database transaction. A transaction (in MySQL InnoDB) has to be persisted with a "COMMIT". The rails testing framework just doesn't do that so your database is in a fresh state after each test. As a consequence, your changes are rolled back.

Changes within a transaction can only be seen by the database connection that started it, from the outside (in your case the `rails db` command) they won't show up.

I hope, this helps.

Comment: add same issue in java, i was using spring framework and when i disabled Transaction, the changes reflected on the database.